# how to delete a static array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, static

so i have written down a piece of code in which there are 4 big arrays stored in the stack 
and after execution of some steps i wanna delete those arrays from the static memory to free up space. How can i do this because i haven't declared these arrays dynamically.....
Please help if there is short and bit easy to understand methodology

for instance my code looks like this

```
£include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
int T;
for (int i=0;i<T;i++)
{
int array[5000];
int array_2[1000];
/* 


more piece of code here

*/

// now how can i delete these arrays from the memory as they aren't //dynamically stored
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't.  You need dynamic storage duration if you want to control when it is created and destroyed.

Comment: You don't use any static memory in your code. All of your variables are with automatic lifetime (and are destroyed upon leaving their relevant scope)

Comment: You only `delete` arrays/pointers that have been allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, `new`, etc. Static arrays are automatically deleted when they go out of scope

Comment: @Yksisarvinen by saying "static" he meant that it was not dynamically allocated, probably.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` would be appropriate for such a case

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for (int i=0;i<T;i++)
> {
> int array[5000];
>
> // now how can i delete these arrays from the memory as they aren't //dynamically stored
> }
> ```

That is an array with **automatic** storage duration (not static). You cannot, nor do you *need* to delete the memory of automatic objects. They are "deleted" (i.e. the objects are destroyed and storage released) **automatically** when the execution goes outside the scope.

In the example, the scope where the array was declared ends right after the comment wondering how to delete the array. So, you don't need to do anything other than let the execution of the program proceed in order to "delete" the array.

Objects with static storage also cannot be deleted. They are created at the beginning of the program (creation may be deferred until first use), and destroyed at the end.

---

P.S. The behaviour of the example is undefined because it uses the indeterminate value of `T`.